# JES Cipher remove spaces and punctuation

Tags: python, jes

I have the following code with the output below. I was wondering how I should change the code in order to get an answer where there are no `z`s in it. In other words, I need it to ignore blanks/spaces and punctuation so that the final output would be `sdfqfqeshqs` instead.

```
def buildCipher(key):
 alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 rest = ""
 for letter in alpha:
  if not (letter in key):
   rest = rest + letter
 print key + rest

def encode2(string, alpha2):
 alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 secret = ""
 for letter in string:
  index = alpha.find(letter)
  secret = secret+alpha2[index]
 print secret
```

`buildCipher("earth")` results in `earthbcdfgijklmnopqsuvwxyz`.

`encode2('this is a test', "earthbcdfgijklmnopqsuvwxyz")` results in `sdfqzfqzezshqs`

Answer (score 0):

`alpha.find(letter)` returns -1 if `letter` isn't in `alpha`. And `alpha2[-1]` is the last letter in `alpha2`. So you just need to skip that letter if it has an index of -1. Like this:

```
def encode2(string, alpha2):
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    secret = ""
    for letter in string:
        index = alpha.find(letter)
        if index != -1:
            secret = secret + alpha2[index]
    print secret
```